# Html tab active

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I use this example code in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp, i Just want that if the user click button **Paris** even the user refresh the page, the tab will still be in **Paris**

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">Enrollment</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')" id="secondOpen" >Student</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')" id="thirdOpen">Parents</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
//is this right?
first = document.getElementById("defaultOpen");
second = document.getElementById("secondOpen");
third = document.getElementById("thirdOpen");
if (second == ('active')){
    document.getElementById("secondOpen").click();
}else if(third == ('active')){
    document.getElementById("thirdOpen").click();
}else{
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
}
</script>
```

this is the example of html, I just want that if the user click the paris, even the user refresh the page the paris will active

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// is this right?
first = document.getElementById("defaultOpen");
second = document.getElementById("secondOpen");
third = document.getElementById("thirdOpen");
if (second == ('active')){
document.getElementById("secondOpen").click();
}else if(third == ('active')){
    document.getElementById("thirdOpen").click();
}else{
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The JS file will be reloaded on page refresh, thus everything will be reset. You need to persist the data in ```localStorage``` or a ```cookie``` and read it back when the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works i have used local storage

[Working Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/prasannabrabourame/pen/qBbWOaQ)

```js
function openCity(cityName) {
  localStorage.setItem('cityName', cityName);
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector(`[data-value=${cityName}]`).className += " active";
}
localStorage.getItem('cityName') !== null ? openCity(localStorage.getItem('cityName')) : openCity('London')
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" data-value="London" onclick="openCity('London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-value="Paris" onclick="openCity('Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-value="Tokyo" onclick="openCity('Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: do i have to change my current script?

Comment: Try to replace the JS and HTML as above.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is:
1. You must save id of tab in Local Storage of the broswer (every you click in another tab, you need to set it in this variable)
2. Every user load again this page, having function get this variable to enable tab.

Comment: can you please provide an example according to my code?

Answer (score 0):

To maintain state across page loads, you have to have some kind of persistent memory...  Websites do this by setting session cookies...

Ref the tutorial at w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

In your case, you need to set a value pair to store the selected tab... when the user selects it, you need to modify the value of the cookie and on page load you need to fetch the value of the cookie..

Comment: can you please provide an example according to my code?

Answer (score 0):

In the script you can add this.

Inside the onclick we store the active tab in localStorage

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  <------your existing code---->
  localStorage.setItem('prevActive', cityName);
}
```

and below your onclick handler we create a new load function and call it at the end.

```js
function load(){
    const cityName = localStorage.getItem('prevActive');
    if(cityName){   
        const tab = document.getElementById(cityName);
        tab.style.display = "block";
        tab.className += " active";
        const tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            if(tablinks[i].textContent === cityName){       
                tablinks[i].className += ' active';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
load();
```

Here is a live [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s9zymo61/)